# Exports is empty with browserify

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, browserify

My code is :

src/index.js

```
const myObject = {
    name : "Object",
    fun : function () {
        console.log('Do some simple stuff');
    },
    data: "some data"

};

export default myObject;
```

and the result with browserify is simply :

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u) ...
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
});

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) .....


var myObject = {
    name: "Object",
    fun: function fun() {
        console.log('Do some simple stuff');
    },
    data: "some data"

};

var X = function X() {
    _classCallCheck(this, X);
};

exports.default = myObject;

//export default exposed;
},{}]},{},[1]);
```

In main.js, using the browserified as module :

```
var x = require('./index');
console.log(x);  // <--- empty object
```

There must be something stupid I have missed :(

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are looking for the following option:

```
  --standalone -s  Generate a UMD bundle for the supplied export name.
                   This bundle works with other module systems and sets the name
                   given as a window global if no module system is found.
```

This makes the bundle importable as CommonJS module (among other things). More information can be found in the [documentation](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage).